# Dynamically add values from a csv in an html table using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv, papaparse

I have a dynamically generated CSV file from another vendor that I am puling in and need to show in a table on my site.  The problem is I need to be able to manipulate the data from the CSV so it can show the corrected values in the html table. In the end I need the HTML table to just display the Products, not the Mixed Sets.

I am using jquery and the papaparse library to get the data and parse it in a table in html.  My codepen is here:

https://codepen.io/BIGREDBOOTS/pen/YQojww

The javascript pulls the initial csv values and display in a table, but I can't figure out how to to add together the values.  If there is a better way of going about this, like converting the CSV to some other form of data like JSON, That is fine too.

My CSV looks like this:

```
product_title,product_sku,net_quantity
Product 1,PRD1,10
Product 2,PRD2,20
Product 3,PRD3,30
Mixed Set 1,MIX1,100
Mixed Set 2,MIX2,50
Mixed Set 3,MIX3,75
```

The Javascript I am using is:

```js
    function arrayToTable(tableData) {
        var table = $('<table></table>');
        $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
            var row = $('<tr class="rownum-' + [i] + '"></tr>');
            $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
                row.append($('<td class="' + [i] + '">'+cellData+'</td>'));
            });
            table.append(row);
        });
        return table;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0453/8489/t/26/assets/sample.csv",
        success: function (data) {
            $('body').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
        }
    });
```

My rules for the mixed set:

- Mixed Set 1 should add 100 to Product 1 and Product 2.
- Mixed Set 2 should add 50 to Product 2 and Product 3.
- Mixed Set 3 should add 75 to Product 1, Product 2 and Product 3.

I'd like to end up with Just the products output, and the correct numbers added to the formula.
The end result would be a table with **Product 1 = 185**, **Product 2 = 245**, and **Product 3 = 155**.

While it would be even better if the top THEAD elements were in a "th", It's fine if that is too complicated.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="rownum-0">
            <td class="0">product_title</td>
            <td class="0">product_sku</td>
            <td class="0">net_quantity</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rownum-1">
            <td class="1">Product 1</td>
            <td class="1">PRD1</td>
            <td class="1">185</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rownum-2">
            <td class="2">Product 2</td>
            <td class="2">PRD2</td>
            <td class="2">245</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rownum-3">
            <td class="3">Product 3</td>
            <td class="3">PRD3</td>
            <td class="3">155</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the size of the dataset you're working with, I suggest you first iterate through all the CSV dataset in order to populate a list of products with the correct values, and then iterate again on that to populate your HTML table:

```
function datasetToMap(data) {
    var ret = {};
    //Initialize a map with all the product rows
    $(data).each(function(index, row) {
        if(row[0].startsWith("Product")) {
            ret[row[1]] = row; //Using the SKU as the key to the map
        }
    });

    //Apply your mixed sets rules to the elements in the ret array        
    $(data).each(function(index, row) {
        if(row[1] === "MIX1") {
            ret["PRD1"][2] += 100;
            ret["PRD2"][2] += 100;
        }
        //Do the same for Mixed sets 2 and 3
    });
    return ret;
}

function appendMapToTable(map) {
    var $table = $('#my-table');
    Object.keys(map).forEach(function(key, i) {
        var rowData = map[key];
        var row = $('<tr class="rownum-' + [i] + '"></tr>');
        $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
            row.append($('<td class="' + [j] + '">'+cellData+'</td>'));
        });
        $table.append(row);
    });
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0453/8489/t/26/assets/sample.csv",
    success: function (data) {
        appendMapToTable(datasetToMap(Papa.parse(data).data));
    }
});
```

Note that this expects a table with id `my-table` to be already present in your HTML: you could manually parse the first row of your CSV data to add the table headings.

Also note that if your CSV dataset is *very* big this is definitely not an optimal solution, since it requires iterating through all its lines twice and then iterating again through all the list built with computed values.

Comment: I commented out the .startswith because it was giving an error, but I am still getting just [object object] output in the html.  https://codepen.io/BIGREDBOOTS/pen/GEbzob

Comment: and my dataset is less than 200 lines, so it this should still be small enough to iterate twice

Comment: There was a typo in my answer, i fixed it. Also, i reimplemented the map iteration and now i see a proper table in my codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awedEp

Comment: I am also seeing  how you built the table, but the numbers are not adding together - they are just appending as a string.  So rather than the value being 110 the value is 10100 , and so on.

Comment: You may need to use `parseInt` the variables to make sure they are added as integers and not as strings: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: That works to get the numbers added together, but then the If statement doesn't work to hide the row.  I commented out the IF in the codepen, but if you add it back it errors out.  https://codepen.io/BIGREDBOOTS/pen/GEbzob?editors=1010

Comment: The best solution I found was to add a class element to the row and remove it with css - I updated my example.   Is there a cleaner way to do this?